# How to substring the string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am using jQuery

I have got below in my string

```
str = "Michael,Singh,34534DFSD3453DS"
```

Now I want my result in three variables.

```
str1 = "Michael"
str2 = "Singh"
str3 = "34534DFSD3453DS"
```

Please suggest!

Thanks

Comment: No need for *"Please suggest!"* and the like. If people are reading your question, their reason for doing so is to reply and help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var strs = str.split(',')` is your best bit. This will create an array for you so

```
strs[0] = "Michael"
strs[1] = "Singh"
strs[2] = "34534DFSD3453DS"
```

However, it is possible to get exactly what you want by adding new items to the `window` object. For this I use the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method of jQuery. It's not necessary (you can just use a for) but I just think it's pretty :). I don't recommend it, but it does show how you can create new variables 'on the fly'.

```
var str = "Michael,Singh,34534DFSD3453DS";

$.each(str.split(','), function(i,item){
   window['str' + (i+1)] = item;
});

console.log(str1); //Michael
console.log(str2); //Singh
console.log(str3); //34534DFSD3453DS
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/bsnak/

Answer (score 5):

No jQuery needed, just javascript:

```
str.split(',')
```

Or, to get your 3 variables:

```
var arr = str.split(','),
    str1 = arr[0],
    str2 = arr[1],
    str3 = arr[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need jQuery. Javascript does that built-in via the [split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
var strarr = str.split(',');
var str1 = strarr[0];
var str2 = strarr[1];
var str3 = strarr[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `split()` and store each word inside an array

```
var str = "Michael,Singh,34534DFSD3453DS"
var myArray = str.split(",");

// you can then manually output them using their index
alert(myarray[0]);
alert(myarray[1]);
alert(myarray[2]);

//or you can loop through them
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    alert(myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not only that JQuery is not needed but that JQuery is not meant to do such tasks. JQuery is for HTML manipulation, animation, event handling and Ajax.